# Typescript - 'SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module' in an external dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, typeorm

How to solve the error of

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

In an external dependency? I am using **typorm** and it is throwing error because of this package inside the docker container. Locally, everything is working fine. I cannot use `type = 'module'` because i am using typescript compiling my code with `target: "es5"`

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": ".",
  }
}
```

**Node version: 17**

Comment: This *really* doesn't make *any* sense. You're in node.js and you're compiling to es***5***? There's *literally* no reason to do that. *Especially* not when you're using a current version of node.js!!! Having es5 as a compile target is for legacy (and I mean a decade old) support for *browsers*.

Comment: "*package inside the docker container*" - why is the package installed in the docker container, and not using the package manager in the environment where you build your TS app?

Comment: @Bergi I mean this is being installed with yarn install. I am not including this package from my local dev. Is there a better way?

Comment: @Jared, I am all good with compiling to the newer versions. But, the problem still persists.